# How to convert String to CLLocationDegrees Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to convert a String that I am retrieving from Firebase and adding it as several annotations on Google Maps. Unfortuanately, my app is crashing whenever it goes through the current code:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Locations").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let lat = (snapshot.value!["Latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
        let lon = (snapshot.value!["Longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue



        let complainLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

        let Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

    })
```

[My JSON Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64vGt.png)

[My Code Block Which Crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFQ4.png)

Here is the code I used for saving data to Firebase

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Location").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).setValue(["Latitude": locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, "Longitude": locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude])
```

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing where it's creating the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, and not where you are doing that forced casting/unwrapping? Check to make sure `value` was not `nil`. Also check to see that `value["Latitude"]` and `value["Longitude"]` were both (a) not `nil`, and (b) string values. With all those `!` forced unwrapping and forced casting operators, there are lots of possible sources of crashes here.

Comment: What's `complainLoc` for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure when you are saving the values of `lat` and `lon` to the database you are saving them as Float or Double..
For retrieving use :

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Locations").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

   if snapshot.exists(){       

    if let locationDictionary = snapshot.value as [String : AnyObject]{

      for each in locationDictionary{          

     //each will bring you every location dictionary in your database for your every user
             let lat = each.value!["Latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
             let lon = each.value!["Longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
             let userId = each.key as! String

             let complainLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)

             let Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)   
       //Every time this for loop complete's itself it will generate a new set of Coordinates for each user   
        }
      }
   }
})
```

EDIT:

Updated code for Firebase 6 and Swift 5

```
let ref = self.ref.child("Locations")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allLocations = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for location in allLocations {
        let lat = location.childSnapshot(forPath: "Latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = location.childSnapshot(forPath: "Longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let userId = location.key
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    }
})
```

note that self.ref points to my Firebase root ref.

Comment: The app still crashes right when I create the let variables lat and lon. I have entered in Latitude and Lngitude correctly as the same way I did for saving data to Firebase.

Comment: @Dravidian Another user wanted to use this answer so I added updated code for Firebase 6 and Swift 5.

Answer (score 7):

**SWIFT 5**

```
let dbLat = Double(latStr)  // Convert String to double
let dbLong = Double(longStr)
```

Use latitude and longitude

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dbLat! , longitude: dbLong! )

let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
 pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dbLat!, longitude:dbLong!)
```