# Once coordinates are saved as String in Firebase, how are they fetched in CLLLoationDegrees to calculate the distance between users?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is how I think it should be done:

1 Make a snapshot of all users’ coordinate Longitude and Latitude entries in Firebase - Print those out in output box to check this step.

2.1 Name a func for the purpose of calculating the distance between the logged in user and all other users

2.2 Inside that function make let coordinate₀ = the logged in user’s coordinates. The database has the String Value of the Coordinates so somehow this needs to be made to CLLLoationDegrees.

2.3 Make a loop for coordinate1 until coordinateX (ie all users in the database) for their coordinates

2.4 Use let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁) and loop for all distances until coordinateX (last one in database)

2.5 Print all the distances in output box. (I don’t need them printed on the app, I am simply getting the distances so that I can rank users by distance)

```
The Database looks like this for each kid:
   "people" : {
    "2jWm6rUfZVYAGkSST0fvVvwolY92" : {
      "Coordinates" : {
        "latitude" : 45.785834,
        "longitude" : -100.406417
      },
      "Education" : "BA Arts",
      "PhotoPosts" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/westpluto1.appspot.com/o/images%2FPhotoPosts?alt=media&token=ccd5a139-b3e1-4ac9-965c-2f09c149fc74",
      "users" : "jackmaster1091@aol.com"
    },


///Part A
  var refArtists : DatabaseReference!
var people = [Userx]()
var latestLocation: [String: Double]?   ////this double was added to get coordinates into firebase under longitude and latitude
```

///Part B

```
   let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid
refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");

refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in
if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
self.people.removeAll()
   for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
   if people.key != thisUsersUid { //do not add this users info to the array
   let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
   let peopleCoordinates = peopleObject?["Coordinates"]  as? String
   let peopl = Userx(Coordinates: peopleCoordinates)
   self.people.append(peopl)  
        }
        self.table.reloadData()
        print(snapshot)
        }
    }

})
```

///Part C

```
func distance (){
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").child("latitude"), longitude: databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").child("longitude")) //////I think this is incorrect even w/o string to CLL conversion because I don’t think longitude and latitude and technically children of Coordinates
        …..
        let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁)
        let distanceInMeters2 = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate2)
        ….
Print …
Print …
```

///////Code based on answer from Jay

```
 let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allCoordinates = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for Coordinates in allCoordinates {
        let lat = Coordinates.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = Coordinates.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let userId = Coordinates.key
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let bcoordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    }
})
```

///2nd updated code:

```
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");

let ref = self.refArtists.child(uid).child("Coordinates")


ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allLocations = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for location in allLocations {
        let userId = location.key
        let coordSnap = location.childSnapshot(forPath: "Coordinates")
        let lat = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        print("   coords: \(lat)  \(lon)")
    }
})
```

////This is the code that now gives two coords printed:

```
let ref = self.refArtists.child(uid).child("Coordinates")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allLocations = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for location in allLocations {
        let userId = location.key
        let lat = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        print("   coords: \(lat)  \(lon)")
    }
```

I expect to rank the users based on location after all this.

Comment: CLLocationDegrees should probably stored as a double and then you can read them in and assign them directly like this `let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)'. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922258/how-to-convert-string-to-cllocationdegrees-swift-2) for working code. I don't understand what the rest of the question is asking though.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is stored as a double. The code you linked makes sense but gives error: 'Any?' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?" Do you know how to fix that? I assume it is an Xcode version type of error. I of course changed "Locations" to what I have it set in firebase.

Comment: Yeah - the code in the question is three years old at this point and not updated for swift 5. I posted an answer that made get you going the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to read the data you're asking about. Here's a summary of each

**Option 1)**

If you have a series of nodes that store coordinate data directly within the node

```
people
   uid_0
      Latitude: xxxxxxxx
      Longitude: yyyyyyy
   uid_1
      Latitude: aaaaaaaa
      Longitude: bbbbbbbb
```

and you want to iterate over each node and create a CoreLocation object for each location node (loc_0, loc_1 or uid_0 uid_1 etc), here's the code to do that.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("people")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for user in allUsers {
        let lat = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "Latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "Longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let userId = user.key
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    }
})
```

note that self.ref points at my Firebase root.

**Option 2)**

If your Firebase structure has the coordinate data stored within a Coordinates node under each parent node then treat the Coordinates node as it's own snapshot, which will enable you to access it's two child coordinates, lat and lon.

```
people
   uid_0
      name: "some user"
      coordinates:
         Latitude: 1
         Longitude: 2
   uid_1
      name: "another user"
      coordinates:
         Latitude: 3
         Longitude: 4
```

Note I added a name child node so you can see how to read that as well.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("people")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    for user in allUsers {
        let userName = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
        let userId = user.key
        let coordSnap = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "coordinates")
        let lat = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let coordinates  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        print("uid: \(userId)  name: \(userName)")
        print("   coords: \(lat)  \(lon)")
    }
})
}
```

and the output will look like this

```
uid: uid_0  name: some name
   coords: 1.0  2.0
uid: uid_1  name: another name
   coords: 3.0  4.0
```

**Option 3)**

If you want to read a single specific node and not iterate over all nodes, here's the code. You will need to know the path to the parent node, which in this case is the uid of the current user.

```
func readThisUsersCoordinates() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let peopleRef = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    let thisPersonRef = peopleRef.child(uid)
    let thisPersonCoordsRef = thisPersonRef.child("Coordinates")
    thisPersonCoordsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let lat = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        let lon = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
        print("   coords: \(lat)  \(lon)")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My database looks a little different. I tried to tweak the code to fit the way my database looks, but I get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, so it is not finding the child. Do you see any error that I don't? My database looks like this: 
People
   Random User ID Code
      DataPoin 1:
      DataPoin 2 :
      Coordinates +
         latitude: ……
         longitude:  …..
   Random User ID Code2 .......

My code based on yours will be put in the original question because it is too long for here:

Comment: 5 minute comment limit just hit. The database structure is clearer in the question than in that comment.

Comment: @noname87f You need to read the coordinates node as a child snapshot. I updated my question to address that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your time. I don't have a 'name' path in my database, so I removed that. I still get an error at the let lat = ... line. However, the previous line let coordSnap works, so the form of this is correct. I don't know if this is because latitude and longitude are not normal child's of Coordinates, but rather a Double listing of it. Do you have any thoughts on why there is an error? I have added the code I used now in the question.

Comment: @noname87f I took that code out of an existing project that works. My guess is that you're not specifying the correct child key name. My structure includes the child key `Latitude` so therefore my code accesses the child `Latitude`. Your structure includes `latitude` (lower case L) so that's the child you should access. My code matches *my* structure so your could would need to match *your* structure. I added reading the `name` node as a template so you you see how to access other child nodes. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it makes sense. I don't know why it isn't matching my structure though. The only thing I can think of is that my latitude and longitude don't constitute as childs. This is a screenshot of my firebase. https://imgur.com/a/XvrGzaB

Comment: @noname87f The 2nd code update in your question has a wrong firebase ref; it resolves to `your_firebase/people/uid/Coordinates' but then your firebase observe is trying to read a child of that node with a key of `coordinates` which doesn't exist. Also, the link your above comment doesn't exactly match what's in your question. I know what the issue is so I'll re-do the answer. In the meantime you should update your question with the exact firebase structure, as text, no images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: @noname87f Keep in mind that the first two parts of my answer were to cover situations where you have a *series of nodes that store coordinate data*. The last part of the answer reads in the coordinates for a specific user.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated the question with JSON copy. Cool to know you can do that. "The last part of the answer reads in the coordinates for a specific user" - doesn't it do that for all users?

Comment: I just saw the edit. I do want it for all users, as after this I am going to group the users based on what their coordinates are. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tried your latest version. It works but as you said not for all users. It printed    coords: 45.785834  -100.406417
   coords: 45.785834  -100.406417
I thought it was just going to print for one user. Hmm..

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll certainly mark it as accept. Thanks for all the help. I think it is giving it twice because I am still using the DataSnapshot line of the 2nd block of code (my oversight - that makes my last comment invalid). I just added the code that it giving 2 coords to question. From here I should be able to figure it out, but is there anything you can see that is wrong that would make it output 2 coords?

Comment: @noname87f As my answer sits, it will only print it once. If you have additional code intermixed with the specific code in my answer (like that for loop in the prior example) it could print twice. Since you are reading a specific node for one user, you definitely don't need a for loop at all. My last example (under Edit) is the correct solution and will only print one line.

Comment: Makes sense. The thing is I want the loop part because I want all coordinates (of all users) so that I can later use them to group users.

Comment: Well then the code in your question won't work as the ref is for a single users node `let ref = self.refArtists.child(uid).child("Coordinates")`. I  have reformatted and updated my answer - has all of the same stuff, just made it easier to read. If you want to iterate over all (user) nodes and get the coordinates within each, use Option 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now. I had thought that let ref was just a general path description.

Comment: Great new, Option 2 worked! It was also good that you added userName option because that should come in handy for when I group users.